# Is it normal to wash an apple, or other fruits, with dish washing liquid?

Tags: fruit, cleaning

I've never seen anyone do that until yesterday. So I wanted to know is this appropriate for when preparing apples for any meal, how about other fruits? Unlike plates, fruits can absorb chemicals.

Comment: Make sure you tell the person you saw doing that to either bump up their life insurance coverage or else stop it.

Comment: @Pointy, assuming they rinse off the soap before eating the apple, I can't see how this practice would endanger their life.

Comment: @LorelC. I was being sarcastic, I assume, because I can't remember that far back. However I would still strongly recommend against using dish detergent to wash vegetables. Vegetable matter in general absorbs water quite readily, and just like a sponge rinsing a vegetable won't get all the absorbed detergent out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you would not use a detergent or soap when washing fruit.

Normally, you would just wash them with water, using a brush on thick skinned produce.

See, for example, [Best Ways to Wash Fruits and Vegetables](http://umaine.edu/publications/4336e/) from the University of Maine extension.

Comment: From what I hear though, there do exist apple exporting companies who wash the apples in soapy water to get rid of germs and pesticides.

Comment: "Pure soap" (as is also used eg in gardening) does not equal "Any dishwashing detergent that happens to be handy".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I've done it for decades using unscented, clear dish detergent (such as Seventh Generation). Just a tiny drop with lots of water.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. It's even essential for some fruits like Apples. That is, if you use a quality, fragrance-free dish soap and a cloth to lightly scrub. Washing with soapy warm water can help remove wax, pesticides, and any fungus that is on the skin that you can't see, but can taste ("tastes like mold").

Answer (score 0):

Just soak your fruits in mild hot water and that should take out any residual items on the fruit

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using an unscented liquid castile soap like Dr. Bronner's. It is all natural and non-toxic. Unscented commercial dish liquid can still contain toxic chemicals and preservatives, even 7th Gen.

Answer (score 0):

Use dish soap only if your produce is layered with wax!

> [(I use a *speck* of Dawn or a spritz of enzymatic vegetable/fruit spray to clean my apples because I hate the added wax.)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4254)

> [Also, it's at least a good idea to rinse with a light soap/vegetable wash since the wax can pick up dirt and bacteria.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4296)